# Python UDF - import/read external files

Tags: python, hive, udf

I would like to import other python/csv files into my python udf to perform some operations.
Like,
Comparing the table data(which flows in as a stream, row by row) to an external .csv row.
When I try to read data of .csv file, it gives me an error

> IOError: File /home/abc/xyz/myfile.csv does not exist

While the code works perfectly well when it is written as a regular python script (not like udf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it right . You can try
ADD FILE  [Your complete file path]
or 
Add FILES [Your directory path].

Because before referring anything on cluster you must add it to the distribution cache so that code there can access that portion.
you can have a look at it.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli

Comment: ADD FILE is working well for .csv files but not .py, for .py files it throws an error "import module not found"

Comment: I have the same question, I need to use an external .txt file in my Python udf file; I have added my python udf file in my .sql file as "ADD FILE address". However, I don't know how could I refer to that .txt file from my python?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about the syntax! It may cause many problems and unfortunately, query language interpreter is not able to show where the problem is coming from and it just shows some generic error report.

Look at kind of the same problem here that was caused by a syntax issue in addressing the file!

[Accessing external file in Python UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45112390/accessing-external-file-in-python-udf)