# Accessing external file in Python UDF

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I am using hive and a python udf. I defined a sql file in which I added the python udf and I call it. So far so good and I can process on my query results using my python function.
However, at this point of time, I have to use an external .txt file in my python udf. I uploaded that file into my cluster (the same directory as .sql and .py file) and I also added that in my .sql file using this command:

```
ADD FILE /home/ra/stopWords.txt;
```

When I call this file in my python udf as this:

```
file = open("/home/ra/stopWords.txt", "r")
```

I got several errors. I cannot figure out how to add nested files and using them in hive.

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All added files are located in the current working directory (`./`) of UDF script.

If you add a **single file** using `ADD FILE /dir1/dir2/dir3/myfile.txt`, its path will be

```
./myfile.txt
```

If you add a **directory** using `ADD FILE /dir1/dir2`, the file's path will be

```
./dir2/dir3/myfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I made this changes and I still get that error although I can see my file in hdfs cluster. :(

Comment: @Reihan_amn what error are you getting? Are you sure it is not the script's error? You can create a UDF that prints all files in current directory (./) to find out if the file is there.

Comment: Yes I added both my .txt file and .p file into hdfs and I can see them there:
    -rw-r--r--   3 reihaneh_amini supergroup        624 2017-07-16 02:41 UDF_test_3.py
-rw-r--r--   3 reihaneh_amini supergroup        133 2017-07-15 16:29 sw.txt

In my script, I am just trying to open this .txt file and read it like this: file = open("./sw.txt", "r")

If I take this out of my script and try to just read a list, it works but it doesn't work for an external file. Error is "Hive Runtime Error while reading or writing the file..."

Comment: @Reihan_amn and just to double check - you do call ADD FILE for both Python script and txt file every time before running Hive query, right? If so, did you try to create a UDF that I described above and see what files are present in the current directory when UDF script is called?

Comment: Yes, I ADDed them and everything looks fine. My text file was really small as well (1k). I just find out that the problem was with opening that txt file in the loop of processing each query result.  :( It was weird, but when I took out the file = open() from there, code worked!!!
Thank you so much for helping me out @Sergey.